# what to do for Update available fileds in vtiger crm and insert new fields when i want to upload csv file?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, crm, vtiger

i need support for update the database fields of vtigercrm based on particular id or insert data if no id is available when i want upload a csv file. for that i have created 2 functions one is selectRecords and 2 is updateDB in filereader.php and 
    public function addRecordToDB($columnNames, $fieldValues) {
        $adb = PearDatabase::getInstance();

```
    $tableName = Import_Utils::getDbTableName($this->user);
    $adb->pquery('INSERT INTO '.$tableName.' ('. implode(',', $columnNames).') VALUES ('. generateQuestionMarks($fieldValues) .')', $fieldValues);
    $this->numberOfRecordsRead++;
}

//reddy editing
public function selectRecords($columnNames, $fieldValues) {
    $adb = PearDatabase::getInstance();

    $tableName = Import_Utils::getDbTableName($this->user);

    $row = $adb->pquery("select * from vtiger_leadsfc where " .$columnNames[0].='?', array($fieldValues[0]));
    $res = $adb->num_rows($row);

    return $res;
}
//reddy editing
public function updateDB($columnNames, $fieldValues) {
    $adb = PearDatabase::getInstance();

    $tableName = Import_Utils::getDbTableName($this->user);
    $adb->pquery('UPDATE vtiger_leadsfc SET ('. implode(',', $columnNames).') VALUES ('. generateQuestionMarks($fieldValues) .')  WHERE ' .$columnNames[0]."=?", array($fieldValues[0]));
    $this->numberOfRecordsRead++;

}
```

and added this code in cscreader.php

```
        if($res > 0){$this->updateDB($fieldNames, $fieldValues);}
        else
        $this->addRecordToDB($fieldNames, $fieldValues);
```

Comment: you described what you did, but forgot to tell what is the problem, what are you getting?

Comment: it is not going to update the database fields i want update the fields aswellas insert the data into the fields if id is not available

Comment: if any body have knowledge in vtiger crm please clarify my doubt because it is very urgent to me.in vtiger crm when user wants to upload csv files, then task is, update the fields of a particular id or insert the data into fields if particular id is not available. thats it.